# Simple 301 redirect in .htaccess with query string does not work with Redirect directive

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-alias

I am trying to redirect a single URL in a .htaccess file with `Redirect`:

```
Redirect 301 /index2.php?option=com_rss&feed=RSS2.0&no_html=1 /something/somethingelse/
```

I have a bunch of other similar rules which work using directory structure URLs, but this one refuses to get processed.

```
Redirect 301 /old/url/ /new/url/
```

Do I have to do anything special?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With [`Redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) you can only test for [URL paths](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directive-dict.html#Syntax), or more specifically, URL path prefixes but not for the URL query. But you can do so with [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =option=com_rss&feed=RSS2.0&no_html=1
RewriteRule ^index2\.php$ /something/somethingelse/? [L,R=301]
```